# Powershell test if excel cell is border

Tags: excel, powershell

Hello is it possible to test the cell is bordered?

```
$SheetName = "2018"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$cell=$worksheet.Columns.Item(299).Rows.Item(194)
```

I would like to test if $cell has enabled border around.

Comment: hmm...
$cell=$worksheet.Columns.Item(299).Rows.Item(194)
$cell2=$worksheet.Columns.Item(300).Rows.Item(194)
$cell.Borders.Color
$cell2.Borders.Color

result:
 $cell.Borders.Color
0
$cell2.Borders.Color
255

Comment: I'm not sure testing the `Color` works - a black border has a color of 0